# Why AsyncMethodBuilder.Start() method need to check if the thread Context has been changed?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'm trying to understand the async-await implementation in c#.

And I notice that AsyncMethodBuilder.Start() has below implementation

```
// Methods
.method public hidebysig static 
    void Start<(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine) TStateMachine> (
        !!TStateMachine& stateMachine
    ) cil managed 
{
    .custom instance void System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    // Method begins at RVA 0x15300c
    // Code size 117 (0x75)
    .maxstack 3
    .locals (
        [0] class System.Threading.Thread,
        [1] class System.Threading.Thread,
        [2] class System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
        [3] class System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
        [4] class System.Threading.SynchronizationContext,
        [5] class System.Threading.SynchronizationContext,
        [6] class System.Threading.Thread,
        [7] class System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
        [8] class System.Threading.ExecutionContext
    )

    // if (stateMachine == null)
    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldobj !!TStateMachine
    IL_0006: box !!TStateMachine
    IL_000b: brtrue.s IL_0014

    // ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.stateMachine);
    IL_000d: ldc.i4.s 60
    IL_000f: call void System.ThrowHelper::ThrowArgumentNullException(valuetype System.ExceptionArgument)

    // Thread currentThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
    IL_0014: call class System.Threading.Thread System.Threading.Thread::get_CurrentThread()
    IL_0019: stloc.0
    // Thread thread = currentThread;
    IL_001a: ldloc.0
    IL_001b: stloc.1
    // ExecutionContext executionContext = currentThread._executionContext;
    IL_001c: ldloc.0
    IL_001d: ldfld class System.Threading.ExecutionContext System.Threading.Thread::_executionContext
    IL_0022: stloc.2
    // ExecutionContext executionContext2 = executionContext;
    IL_0023: ldloc.2
    IL_0024: stloc.3
    // SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext = currentThread._synchronizationContext;
    IL_0025: ldloc.0
    IL_0026: ldfld class System.Threading.SynchronizationContext System.Threading.Thread::_synchronizationContext
    IL_002b: stloc.s 4
    .try
    {
        // stateMachine.MoveNext();
        IL_002d: ldarg.0
        IL_002e: constrained. !!TStateMachine
        IL_0034: callvirt instance void System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine::MoveNext()
        // }
        IL_0039: leave.s IL_0074
    } // end .try
    finally
    {
        // SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext2 = synchronizationContext;
        IL_003b: ldloc.s 4
        IL_003d: stloc.s 5
        // Thread thread2 = thread;
        IL_003f: ldloc.1
        IL_0040: stloc.s 6
        // if (synchronizationContext2 != thread2._synchronizationContext)
        IL_0042: ldloc.s 5
        IL_0044: ldloc.s 6
        IL_0046: ldfld class System.Threading.SynchronizationContext System.Threading.Thread::_synchronizationContext
        IL_004b: beq.s IL_0056

        // thread2._synchronizationContext = synchronizationContext2;
        IL_004d: ldloc.s 6
        IL_004f: ldloc.s 5
        IL_0051: stfld class System.Threading.SynchronizationContext System.Threading.Thread::_synchronizationContext

        // ExecutionContext executionContext3 = executionContext2;
        IL_0056: ldloc.3
        IL_0057: stloc.s 7
        // ExecutionContext executionContext4 = thread2._executionContext;
        IL_0059: ldloc.s 6
        IL_005b: ldfld class System.Threading.ExecutionContext System.Threading.Thread::_executionContext
        IL_0060: stloc.s 8
        // if (executionContext3 != executionContext4)
        IL_0062: ldloc.s 7
        IL_0064: ldloc.s 8
        IL_0066: beq.s IL_0073

        // ExecutionContext.RestoreChangedContextToThread(thread2, executionContext3, executionContext4);
        IL_0068: ldloc.s 6
        IL_006a: ldloc.s 7
        IL_006c: ldloc.s 8
        IL_006e: call void System.Threading.ExecutionContext::RestoreChangedContextToThread(class System.Threading.Thread, class System.Threading.ExecutionContext, class System.Threading.ExecutionContext)

        // }
        IL_0073: endfinally
    } // end handler

    // (no C# code)
    IL_0074: ret
} // end of method AsyncMethodBuilderCore::Start
```

which I can't understand is, why in this method it checks the SynchronizationContext and ExecutionContext has been changed?

I think this Start() method always run synchronizly and there is no wait in it. so the thread runs this method has no chance switch to another context.

Comment: Your statement that global property (like synchronization context) can’t change between creating an arbitrary object (like Task) and calling a method on such object is strange...

Comment: It's easier to look at [the actual source (including comments)](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1d9e50cb4735df46d3de0cee5791e97295eaf588/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/CompilerServices/AsyncMethodBuilderCore.cs#L34-L36).

Answer (score 0):

After read the comments in source code, I think I can explain myself. If I am wrong please tell me : )

Imagine that you have some code like below

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
    // do something.

    task.Wait(); // if DoSomething() running in a task, in this point, wait will suspend current task and cause a thread switch.
    await Task.Delay(1);

    // do some other things.
}
```

In this case, when running into AsyncMethodBuilder.Start() -> stateMachine.MoveNext(), It will have a thread switch in it, so that check if thread context has changed is make sense.